# How do I use superscript and subscript in PowerPoint 2013?

Tags: powerpoint, subscript, superscript, powerpoint-2013

In order to write oxygen with its chemical sign O2, is there a possible way to type it without copy/pasting it in the 2013 version of PowerPoint?

In addition, I want to write 2^2 without the '^' expression to get a square indicated above the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're called "superscript" and "subscript". You'll find them in the font properties.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did this, but in this way:

1. I wrote O2
2. I selected the '2'
3. Right clicked with the mouse on this -> FONT...
4. Effects side I saw superscript and subscript